# .NET Framework 3.5 EntityCollection OrderBy Question

Tags: entity-framework, sql-order-by

I'm using .NET Framework 3.5 with ASP.NET MVC and I'm using Linq To Entity for my data objects.

I have a Promotion Object that has a 1 to many relationship to the Location object.

What I want to do is take the collection of Locations from the Promotion object and sort those without putting them into another variable. Something like...

```
promotionEntity.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.Distance);
```

But it does nothing to the *.Locations collections. Is there a way that I can have that EntityCollection sorted how I need without putting it in another List or variable?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the type of locations is IEnumerable you can just assign the result of OrderBy:

`promotionEntity.Locations = promotionEntity.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.Distance)`

If the type is something like `List<Location>` then you will probably have to create a new List:

`promotionEntity.Locations = 
    new List<Location>(promotionEntity.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.Distance));`

Comment: I'd go with `promotionEntity.Locations = promotionEntity.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.Distance).ToList();` in the second case.

Comment: This is more what I'm trying to do. the promotionEntity.Locations is typed as an EntityCollection and the *.OrderBy makes it a System.Linq.IOrderedEnumberable<T> and they do not automatically cast. It says there is an explicit conversion does exist. I just haven't figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use [*EntityCollection.CreateSourceQuery Method*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896438.aspx):

```
var promotionEntity = context.Promotions.First();
var sq = product.Locations.CreateSourceQuery().OrderBy(l => l.Distance);
promotionEntity.Locations.Attach(sq);
```

Or if you don't care about the resultant object's type can do projection inside an anonymous type:

```
var promotionEntity = context.Promotions.Select(p => new 
{
    p,
    Locations = p.Locations.OrderBy(l => l.Distance)
}).First();
```